# How to authenticate with a service account or OAuth consent automatically for Google Drive API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to make a simple POST request as the following :

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "4ba78bf0-6a47-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a77", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://www.example.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myChangesChannelDest", // (Optional) Your changes channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration date and time.
}
```

From this [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/push) and i need the `auth_token_for_current_user` value from authentication.

I need to make this request from python, but i am unable to find a documentation on how to use a client library or getting the authenticated token to use a POST request with the `requests` package.

My question is how to authenticate for this API ? I prefer an automated solution than an OAuth consent screen that i should fill manually.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you want to do it with a post request why not just use the client library?

Comment: What have you tried so far? On my end, I attempted to pass a token from a service account authentication for the Drive API in a simple POST request, and I received the following error: `"Request is missing the required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie, or another valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."` It appears that `auth_token_for_current_user` will only accept a token from OAuth 2 authentication or any authentication method with web sign-in.

Comment: I am willing to do it with the client library if i can, but i don't really understand how to use the `build` method and there is no documentation about it. 
besides, i only need to do this request once sometimes very rarely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

## auth with service account

```
def build_service(credentials, scope, delegated_user):

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        credentials,
        scopes=scope,
    )
    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(delegated_user)
    try:
        return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - any errors returned.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

## Request

```
def get_watch(drive_service, token):
channel_id = str(uuid.uuid4()),

body = {
    "id": channel_id,
    "type": "web_hook",
    "address": "https://www.example.com/notifications"
}
return     drive_service.changes().watch(body=body,pageToken=token).execute()
```

which gives you the following results.

> {'kind': 'api#channel', 'id': 'REDACTED', 'resourceId': 'REDACTED', 'resourceUri': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes?alt=json&pageToken=45', 'expiration': '1698691440000'}

## Note: PageToken

Make sure you created the page token first

```
def get_start_page_token(drive_service):
    response = drive_service.changes().getStartPageToken(
        driveId = DRIVE_ID,
        supportsAllDrives = True
        ).execute()
    token = response.get("startPageToken")
    print(F'Start token: {token}')
    return token
```

## stop watch

```
def stop_watch(drive_service, channel_id,resource_id):


    body = {
        "id": channel_id,
        "resourceId" : resource_id
    }
    return drive_service.channels().stop(body=body).execute()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this seems to be working ! 
However i am getting this error : 
`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch?alt=json returned "Required parameter: pageToken". Details: "[{'message': 'Required parameter: pageToken', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'required', 'location': 'pageToken', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">`
But i don't see any `pageToken` attribute in the documentation : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/push#making-watch-requests

Comment: If you update your answer to make it actually working with the correct parameters i will accept it, for now i can't because people who will see that will think it's working

Comment: The documentation is ugly.  Page token is the token you got back from [getStartPageToken](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/changes/getStartPageToken)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, can i ask you how do you know / find how to write this without any documentation ? Congratz really

Comment: I have been working with these apis for 12+ years.  I have been though most of the source code.   I know how they work.